# postgresql query to select rows in a table that don't exist in a link to another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
Table "contact"

id  | customer_id
----+------------- 
1   | 123
2   | 123
3   | 123
4   | 888
```

And

```
Table "user_contact"

user_id | contact_id
--------+------------
456     | 1
456     | 2
789     | 3
999     | 4
```

To select all of contacts that have a customer_id of 123 **and** exist in `user_contact` with a `user_id` of 456, I can go:

```
SELECT
    contact.id
FROM
    contact JOIN user_contact ON
        contact.id = user_contact.contact_id
WHERE
    contact.customer_id = 123 AND
    user_contact.user_id = 456
```

How can I select all of the contacts that have a `customer_id` of 123 but **don't** exist in `user_contact` with a `user_id` of 456?

Trying:

```
SELECT
    contact.id
FROM
    contact JOIN user_contact ON
        contact.id = user_contact.contact_id
WHERE
    contact.customer_id = 123 AND
    user_contact.user_id != 456
```

Obviously doesn't work as it returns a row for each `contact` in `user_contact` that has a `user_id` != 456.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple `LEFT JOIN` and check that the resulting `user_contact` part does not exist (ie. `IS NULL`);

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM contact c
LEFT JOIN user_contact uc ON c.id = uc.contact_id AND uc.user_id='456'
WHERE c.customer_id = '123' AND uc.contact_id IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/19171/4).

Answer (score 1):

This is generally better tackled with a NOT EXISTS correlated subquery, as performance is not so dependent on the number of child records per parent.

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM   contact c
where  c.customer_id = '123' and
       not exists (
         select null
         from   user_contact uc
         where  c.id       = uc.contact_id and
                uc.user_id = '456')
```

This will use a semi-join, which stops after finding a single child record.